# xargs sed is renaming files instead of replacing contents

Tags: linux, sed, xargs, macos

Complex command:

```
git ls-files | grep -E '\.(ts|xml|json|html|js|scss)$' | xargs sed -ie s/##tag##/1.0.0/g
```

And in the past it works and replaces in the correct way.

So file **version-info.html**:

```
<p>Version: ##tag##</p>
```

And now it creates a second file instead.

- version-info.html
- version-info.htmle

Why it adds an `e` at the end?

When I remove `-ie` then its showing the content.
When I remove only the `e` from `-ie` then there is an error.

Thanks in Advance for ideas!

Comment: You have asked `sed` to create a backup file with the filename suffix `e`.  You did this by giving the letter `e` as an argument to the `-i` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing `-ie` to `sed`, means to make changes in-place, while keeping a backup file named as filename+`e`.

From `man sed`

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

If you want to use any other parameter along with `sed -i` you have to use them separated or at least don't place that parameter just after `-i` for not being interpreted as the suffix of the backup file.

```
sed -i.bak -e ...
```

in order to create a backup file with the `.bak` extension as the suffix, or

```
sed -i -e ...
```

for not creating any backup file.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explaination. Now I understand the problem and its solved.

Comment: Ah no, @thanasisp, its not working. Not with `-i -e` its creating a file named `.xml-e` 

Comment: why not just `xargs sed -i 's/##tag##/1.0.0/g'` ? Ot try `sed -e <expression> -i ` BTW are you on MacOS? Install GNU sed, usually mac comes with a broken sed. You will use it later as `gsed`, as the naming convention has changed.